# How to pass number of arguments in a function to use in IN clause Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Below is a sample scenario for what actually am trying to achieve.

```
create table sample (id int,val text);

insert into sample values (1,'A');
insert into sample values (2,'B');
insert into sample values (3,'C');
insert into sample values (4,'Z');
insert into sample values (5,'X');
insert into sample values (6,'Y');
```

Then create a `Function` to get `val` from *table* `Sample`(don't say that you can use *select* for this because this is just an example to elaborate what is my problem)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FN_GETVAL (ids text) returns table ( val text) as 
$$
select val from sample where id in(ids); -- here i want to pass the ids for example 1,5
                                         --select val from sample where id in(1,5); 
$$
language sql
```

When creating this `ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = text`

so how to create a  function for this - `select * from FN_GETVAL(1,5)`

---

Note : *the id can be 2 or more*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would pass the values as an array:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FN_GETVAL (id_list int[]) 
   returns table (val text) 
as 
$$
  select val 
  from sample 
  where id = ANY (id_list);
$$
language sql ;

select *
from fn_getval(array[1,2,3]);
```

Comment: i was almost reaching there.

Comment: It can also be convenient to mark it `VARIADIC`, so you can call it as `fn_getval(1,2,3,42)` or as `fn_getval(VARIADIC array_agg(some_vol))`, depending on which form you need.